# Get XRP Blockchain Data

Tags: cryptocurrency, xrp

Any suggestions to get the Blockchain Data for XRP?
https://xrpl.org/ledger.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can retrieve XRP Ledger blockchain data using the `ledger` method.

Another convenient way is to query the BigQuery database on the Google Cloud Platform:

- [Examples](https://medium.com/@silkjaer/an-exploration-in-the-xrp-ledger-with-bigquery-46cdb9102c1f)
- [Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzyytL8VImo)
- [Data importer code](https://github.com/WietseWind/fetch-xrpl-transactions)

Answer (score 0):

try Bitquery's Explorer for ready-made stats on XRP. https://explorer.bitquery.io/ripple

You can also write your own queries in the IDE https://ide.bitquery.io/ , if you are comfortable with GraphQL.
Here's an example: https://ide.bitquery.io/XRP-Transaction-Details